# Why is the study of homology important?

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ra.rings-and-algebras, ho.history-overview, harmonic-analysis

In some fields of studies, for example, Amenability of Banach algebras and $L^2$-Betti numbers, some chain complexes are studied, why is the study of these creatures important? When and why do these objects and their related structures enter mathematics?

Comment: You can  blame Poincare for this.  http://www.algtop.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/docs_conf_ren-uir-2013_slides_RabatTalk.2013.pdf .  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homology_(mathematics)

Comment: Homology is an invariant that is usually easy to compute; and that nonetheless has some distinguishing power : in that way it is a good invariant.

Comment: The “two broad” closer has a point: see e.g. https://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/7414

Comment: Abstractly, exact sequences provide powerful tools in computations, because a simple check that something is $0$ will give you an existence result. Therefore measuring the defect of a chain complex from being exact is just as important. But I also agree that this question is too broad for this forum.

Comment: This is a natural question but I don't think one can give a proper answer on MO. As others have said it is really too broad. (Incidentally, most people who have worked on versions of amenability of Banach algebras do not work very much with the Hochschild chain complex -- there is a lot more to Hochschild cohomology of Banach algebras than the "usual stuff" on amenability)

Comment: If you are wondering why people look at cohomology of associative algebras (this motivates the continuous Hochschild cohomology of Banach algebras) or cohomology of groups (this motivates L^2-Betti numbers) then you *might* get something out of Weibel's book on homological algebra, but I'm not sure how accessible this is without learning all the relevant homological algebra